# A Question about Chromatic numbers and the size of the largest Independent set in a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

From my textbook for Graph Theory:

a) If $q$ is the size of the largest independent set in a graph $G$, show that $\chi(G) \cdot q \geq n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$.

b) If the minimum degree of a vertex is $d$ in an $n$-vertex graph $G$, then use the result from part (a) to show that $\chi(G)(n-d)\geq n$, and hence $\chi(G) \geq n/(n-d)$.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Comment: I don't know the command to produce the symbol for Chromatic number, sorry.

Comment: Is there a multiplication sign somewhere in your a)? In general $\chi(G)$ as the chromatic number of $G$ will be understood. .

Comment: Hint for a: color classes form independent sets.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

a) Let $c$ be a proper coloring of $G$ in $\chi(G)$ colors. Then each color class of $c$ is an independent set, and thus there are at most $q$ vertices in each of the $\chi(G)$ color classes.

b) You need to show that $n-d \geq q$. In other words, the largest possible size of an independent set is $n-d$. Let $v$ be a vertex of minimum degree $d$. Then none of the neighbors of $v$ can be in an independent set with $v$, so the largest an independent set that contains $v$ can be is $\dots$